# how to disable annoying eclipse tag descriptions on hover?

Tags: eclipse, validation, aptana

I have installed Eclipse 3.61 ( + Aptana 2) and really tired of annoying validation messages. Removed all but cant get rid of this. How can I disable these popups?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's tucked away under the preferences of the "Structured Text Editor".

[image: Removing Hovers]

Comment: Man I already tried that, it must be something about Aptana. Thanks though.